# punctured Mobius band in high dimension

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, geometric-topology

Let $M^{n+1}$ be the non-trivial line bundle over sphere $S^n$. When $n=1$, $M^2$ is Mobius band and the 
punctured space $M^2\setminus *\simeq S^1$. How about $M^{n+1}\setminus *$ in general?
Does $M^{n+1}\setminus *\simeq S^n$?

Comment: I don't think your M is defined for $n>1$ since $S^n$ is simply connected, so it has non-nullhomotopic circles for the line bundle to switch orientation over

Comment: @Carl And is it true that punctured Möbius band is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$? If the code for fundamental polygon of the Möbius band is $abac$, it seems to me that the punctured Möbius band has deformation retraction to the boundary, which is 8-shaped space, not a circle.

Comment: @FrankScience Yeah you're right about that as well (although you mean to say it retracts onto the boundary of that square.  It does not retract onto the boundary of the mobius band (which is a topological circle))

Comment: Oops, also in the first comment I meant to say "NO non-nullhomotopic circles..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every line bundle is trivial if it is orientable. But if the first cohomology of the space is trivial (which is true for simply connected spaces), the bundle will be orientable, since the first Stiefel Whitney class is an obstruction to this. Hence any line bundle over a higher dimensional sphere is trivial.