# Fundamental group of Möbius strip using Van Kampen

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, group-homomorphism, fundamental-groups

I know that the fundamental group of the Möbius strip $M$ is $\pi_1(M)=\mathbb{Z}$ because it retracts onto a circle. However, I am trying to show this using Van Kampen's theorem.

As usual I would take a disk inside the Möbius band as an open set $U$ and the complement of a smaller disk as $V$. Then $\pi_1(U)=0$ and $\pi_1(U\cap V)=\langle \varepsilon\mid\rangle = \mathbb{Z}$. The puncture Möbius strip retracts to a circle given by the boundary, so $\pi_1(V)=\langle \alpha\mid\rangle = \mathbb{Z}$.

When I compute $i_{2*}:\pi_1(U\cap V)\to\pi_1(V)$ I get that $\varepsilon\mapsto \alpha^2$, because when we go around in the polygon representation we pass through the boundary twice in the same direction.

However, this would implye that $\pi_1(M)=\langle \alpha\mid \alpha^2\rangle = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

What I am doing wrong? I guess my computation of $i_{2*}$ is wrong somehow, but I  don't see why.

Comment: You'll have a hard time retracting the punctured Mobius strip to a circle.

Comment: The sides of the mobius strip is a circle, but the retract has a second segment from one point on that circle to another. It is essentially two loops.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I read in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153928/punctured-mobius-band-in-high-dimension) that it is $S^1$. And when I draw the pictures I don't see two different circles, because the glued side is connecting the boundary circle with itself.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok I had to do it with a piece of paper to see you're right, now I think I know what was wrong in my pictures.